# Sum of rows in column value_id in table3, taking value of the value_id from table2, where seller_id is also from table3 and row status=1

Tags: join, sum

Tablename = 'eg_posts', Columnname = 'value_id'

I want to echo the sum of rows created by a seller in the column value_id. The value_id is an integer. The value of the value_id is saved in another table 'eg_values' in column 'value'

```
    <?php
$sid = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "select sum(value) from eg_values, value_id from eg_posts where eg_posts.seller_id='$sid' and eg_posts.value_id=eg_values.value, status=1";
$q = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($q);
echo 'Total Posts = USD ' . $row[0];?>.00
```

Comment: Honeslty, I am totally a newbie who learns from asking a lot of questions

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  You need to join the 2 tables.

```
select sum(value)
   from eg_values
   join eg_posts using(value_id)
   group by seller_id;
```